# how to set location of "this field is required message " in tagfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to set the location of "this field is required message " in the tag field. side location.actually, I want to set this property in tag field and it doesn't work.how to set the location of "this field is required message " in the tag field. side location.actually, I want to set this property in tag field and it doesn't work.how to set the location of "this field is required message " in the tag field. side location.actually, I want to set this property in tag field and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question: 1. Be more specific about your question. 2. Add code examples.

Comment: @GalAbra the problem is message is displayed in center .if we do :cmp.allowblank=false;

Answer (score 0):

Use **allowBlank: false** &&  **msgTarget: 'side'** if you want  "this field is required message " in the tag field to the side .Here is the fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2cmt&view/editor

```
{
          xtype: 'tagfield',
          fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
          store: shows,
          displayField: 'show',
          valueField: 'id',
          queryMode: 'local',
          allowBlank: false,
          msgTarget: 'side',
          filterPickList: true
      }
```

Comment: message is displayed in center .if we do  :cmp.allowblank=false;

Comment: i directly want message and not that symbol.like normal fields.btw thanks.but it didn't solved my problem.